# MySQL loop with ASP

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I've been trying to get some ASP code to work for a while and simply can't (I'm a PHP guy and contracted someone to do this for me, but he refuses to answer emails now). So I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot an issue I'm having and perhaps explain what the issue is with this code. Here is the code:

```vb
'------------ Connect to MySQL --------------------------
sConnection = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=" & sServer & "; DATABASE=" & sDBName &"; UID=" & sDBUser & ";PASSWORD=" & sDBPass & "; PORT=3306;"
Set oConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.Open(sConnection)
Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'------------ Connect to MySQL --------------------------

'Checks if the cookie exists
sCookieValue = Request.Cookies(sCookieName)
bCookieFound = CBool(Len(sCookieValue) > 0)

if bCookieFound then

    oRS = oConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE id=" & sCookieValue )
    Dim bSDFound
    Dim sDate
    bSDFound = false
    Do while NOT oRS.EOF
        bSDFound = true
        sDate = oRS("date")
        oRS.MoveNext ' Next record
    Loop

    ' Check if found in the DB
    if bSDFound then
        'Convert from universal Date format
        Dim dateDB
        dateDB = CDate(Mid(sDate, 1, 10) & " " & Mid(sDate, 12, 8))

        'Check if is longer than 1 hour old            
        if DateDiff("n", dateDB, Now) > 60 then
            Response.Redirect urlLogin
        else
            'If it is not older than an hour, update it to the current timestamp and redirect
            oConnection.Execute("UPDATE sessions set date=Now() WHERE id=" & sCookieValue )
            Response.Redirect urlWelcome
        end if
    else
        Response.Redirect urlLogin
    end if

else
    Response.Redirect urlLogin
end if
```

I'm quite certain that the issue is somewhere in the "while NOT loop", but I don't know enough about ASP to figure it out.

I do know:
- MySQL information being used is correct,
- The code works when the while loop is removed.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Tag this as ASP as ASP is different to ASP.NET!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that. I've gone ahead and changed the tag.

Comment: What part does not work ? do you get an error ? (*if so what does the error say*). Do you get an unexpected result ? (*if so what did you expect and what happened*). Other than that the code look ok, olthough you should not use a loop since you only have a single value in the result set..

Comment: `oRS = oConnection.Execute(` should be `set oRS = oConnection.Execute(`

Comment: Gaby - your suggestion worked. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oRS = oConnection.Execute( should be set oRS = oConnection.Execute(
– Gaby aka G. Petrioli